# A positive definite matrix A can be express as a polynomial of $ A^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, positive-definite

I have recently come across this question in my studies of matrix theory stating :

> If A is a real symmetric positive definite matrix, we are asked to show it can be expressed as a polynomial of $ A^2 $

I thought about using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem via the characteristic polynomial, by I cannot guarantee only even powers of A in this matrix equation, so I am stuck and require help here. I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda_i\geq 0$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$
and let $e_i(x)=\prod_{j\neq i}(x-\lambda_j^2)/\prod_{j\neq i}(\lambda_i^2-\lambda_j^2)$. Then $e_i(A^2)$ is a projection onto the eigenspace associated with $\lambda_i^2$ (of $A^2$), whence with $\lambda_i$ (of $A$). Then
$$ A=\sum_i \lambda_i e_i(A^2)$$
If I am not mistaking one only need $A$ diagonalizable and the $\lambda_i^2$'s being distinct.

Answer (score 4):

This has little to do with Cayley-Hamilton theorem. You only need to find a polynomial $p$ such that $p(\lambda_i^2)=\lambda_i$ over a set of *distinct positive* numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k$.

Comment: thanks, but how can we guarantee the existence or construction of such a polynomial?

Comment: @zbigniew2015 You need [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). And why Lagrange interpolation is possible in this case is somehow related to the positivity of the lambda's. I'll leave you to figure out why.

Comment: Well, it's really more the fact that the squares of the distinct lambdas are still distinct that really matters. But of course the positivity is a sufficient condition for this.